# Retrofit 2 : End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

Have made a thorough searching to this particular problem but while implementing answers under each question I encountered, am still getting the same output:

```
 End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

I perfomed my Request on PostMan and I got expected output:
[Here is the Screenshot of the Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t885I.jpg)

**Interfaces**

```
 @POST(Constant.API_REQUEST)
    Observable<ServerResponse> postToWinnersList(@Body ServerRequest serverRequest);
```

**ApiClient**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder;
    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;


    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
        if (retrofit == null){
//            create instance of Httpclient
            okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
            }
//            instance of retrofit
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL).
                    addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()).
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Retrofit/RxJava Request Code:**

```
     Observable<ServerResponse> response = apiInterface.postToWinnersList(serverRequest);
                response.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ServerResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(ServerResponse serverResponse) {
                                AVLoadingIndicatorView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                txtSubmitWinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                AVLoadingIndicatorView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                txtSubmitWinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {
                                showShortMsg(getString(R.string.submit_success));
                            }
                        });
```

Kindly help, thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please, post your ServerResponse class as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get that error when something is wrong with your `json` response, Check again to make sure both the error response and correct response are well formatted.

Enter wrong credentials using postman and see what the output looks like.

Comment: I got the same error. I copy response from API but still got this error

Answer (score 9):

You can get this error when you are expecting an object in the response, but the API doesn't return anything other than result codes (200,...). Options:
- Check that the API really returns a `ServerResponse`.
- If you don't really need it to return anything, use `Observable<Response<Void>>` instead of `Observable<ServerResponse>`

Comment: and what if either onSuccess and not in success I am receiving Object?

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same exception yesterday and figured out that I was using a LogOutResponse data class as the expected response for the API, but then I got to know that the API doesn't return any JSON response corresponding to that data class, in fact, it didn't return anything in the body and only returned result code (200,300,400, etc). So I changed my implementation from:

```
@POST("logout")
    suspend fun logout(): LogOutResponse
```

to

```
@POST("logout")
suspend fun logout(): Response<Unit>
```

Earlier retrofit tried to parse a JSON response at line 1 when there was no JSON there, that's why it threw that exception.

After the changes, the code worked fine as Response is a default retrofit class and Unit type inside it is of void type meaning we don't expect anything in return (no JSON body in response).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think in Constant.API_REQUEST you are not appending "/".Let me know if it is right.

ex.`@POST("index.php") // wrong`

```
@POST("/index.php") //correct way
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment:

This is what I used and it even work for others request

 @POST("api/")
    Observable<ServerResponse> postToWinnersList(@Body ServerRequest serverRequest);
 
 now changed to 
 
 @POST("/api/")
Observable<ServerResponse> postToWinnersList(@Body ServerRequest serverRequest);

still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when an answer is void.
To correct this error make sure that in the return of the request there will be void.

Eg.
Interface whit kotlin

```
@POST("endPoint/")
fun relatarProblema(@Body serverRequest: ServerRequest ): Call<Void>
```

Don't forget to override the return type in the api call.

example whit Kotlin

```
call.enqueue (object: Callback <Void> {
override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>, response: Response<Void>) {

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {

        }
```

})

Answer (score 0):

When I used Coroutines what helped was to basically not return anything from the method:

```kotlin
@GET
@Headers("X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest")
suspend fun methodCall(
    @Url url: String
)
```